# Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory

Tags: ionic3

I am trying to build apk using following command

```
ionic cordova build android.
```

But it's giving me error each time:

```
 Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
 Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to 
 enter image description herevalid SDK directory.
```

Even Android home path is set correctly in .bash_profile

```
   export PATH=${PATH}:/home/sunil-rawat/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/home/sunil- 
  rawat/Android/sdk/tools
  export ANDROID_HOME=/home/sunil-rawat/Android/sdk
```

I am using Ionic 3

[image]

Ionic info is

```
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.2
  Cordova Platforms  : android 5.1.1
  Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.5
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
 export ANDROID_HOME=/home/sunil-rawat/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools